# What is the maximum sprite sheet size I can use for android devices?

Tags: libgdx, sprite-sheet, texture-packing

What is the maximum sprite sheet size I can use for android devices? I heard that there is a limit, because some devices can't handle large images. Is 8196x4092px still okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a texture resolution of **8196x4092px** is too big, you should try to reduce the resolution of the spritesheet, or dividing your **spritesheet** into diferent spritesheets then assembling them

cause 8196x4092px may cause you problem on some devices

**Max Texture Size**

You can query the maximum texture width and height with the following:

```
IntBuffer buf = BufferUtils.newIntBuffer(16);
Gdx.gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, buf);
int maxSize = buf.get(0);
```

Generally, most modern computers allow for at least 4096x4096 textures, but if you want to be really safe, you can limit yourself to 2048x2048. If you are targeting Android, iOS, WebGL, or another OpenGL ES device, you might be safer sticking with 1024x1024 or less, unless you are absolutely sure of your target audience.

from Libgdx wiki, for more please see : 
https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Textures

Good luck